# Chrome opens pdf files in small window

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I tried to find solution in forums but still have no answer for the problem

1. Chrome Version 77.0.3865.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)
2. Windows 10 (v. 1903). OS build 18362.925
3. Resizing with Chrome's "Inspect" tool
4. In incognito mode everything works properly
5. Nope

[image: Screenshot of pdf in Chrome]

Comment: What version of Chrome, what operating system? What solutions have you tried? Does this occur in an Incognito window? A new profile? Please [edit] and update your question.

Comment: Thanks for your attention:) 
I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled Reverso extension which resolved the issue.

Thanks to all!)

Answer (score 0):

While an extension might cause this, a [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=271452) might have the same effect.

What's happing is this: the built-in PDF viewer uses CSS to style the page. And something is preventing that CSS from being applied correctly.

Comment: this is being worked on in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=271452

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue, but resolved it myself.

1. Right click on the file.
2. select open with PDF view.

Now, the default is changed to PDF view from the Gallery earlier. When you click on any pdf file now, it'll open in a regular size and not in a small window.

If you do not have the Pdf viewer extension already installed, you may have to install / enable it.

However, after doing this, the image files opened in a small window. To resolve this, I once again changed the default to photos.

Now, both the Pdf as well as images open in a big window in google photos.

Hope this helps.